# Get SVG attribute after <animate> has started

Tags: svg-animate

Is there a way to read the value (final or intermediate) of a SVG attribute, like x1 in the following example, after a svg-animation is started/applied?

The result of .getAttribute is always the initial value, not the current one used to render the element.

After many cumulative animations, it gets hard to keep track of every one to calculate it, so some property, or some way to apply it to the element, must exist. CSS animations do get .commitStyles and I found no SVG counterpart.

```js
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log(theLine.getAttribute("x1")); //always 10, but should change to become 100 at the end
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<svg id="mainSvg" width="400" height="300">
    <line id="theLine" x1="10" y1="100" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke: #000">
        <animate
            attributeName="x1"
            begin="1s"
            dur="2s"
            values="20;100"
            calcMode="spline"
            keySplines="0.6 0 0.4 1"
            repeatCount="1"
            fill="freeze"
            additive="sum">
        </animate>
    </line>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SVGAnimatedString.animVal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString/animVal) to retrieve the currently animated value.

```
let x1 = theLine.x1.animVal.value;
```

```js
lineAni.beginElement();
let interval = setInterval(getAttAnim, 100);
let loops = 50;
let i=0;
function getAttAnim(){
  if(i<=loops){
      let x1 = theLine.x1.animVal.value;
      i++
      //console.log(x1)
      currentVal.textContent = x1;
    
  }else{
      clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="mainSvg" width="400" height="300">
    <line id="theLine" x1="10" y1="100" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke: #000">
        <animate
            id="lineAni"
            attributeName="x1"
            begin="indefinite"
            dur="5s"
            values="10;100"
            calcMode="linear"
            repeatCount="0"
            fill="freeze"
            >
        </animate>
    </line>
</svg>
<p id="currentVal">10</p>
```

Comment: Wow! Never saw it in the MDN docs. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! But you might consider to revise your question title – actually it's more about getting the **current/intermediate** value while animating (not sure what would be the best term here) since the final state is obviously the defined last one specified in the SMIL animation.

Comment: Done! I changed the question too. Now, it should be clear that the problem is about SVG-animate element, not a CSS animation.

Comment: Perfect! Now it should be easier to find for others.